# Configuration for Celery during deployment

Tags: django, email, redis, celery, railway

I am trying to deploy a django app on railway where I am using celery for sending email and redis as celery_broker but When I deploy it then celery don't send emails. I also use Redis Cloud and use the url of it as celery_broker_url. I want to know how to run celery on Redis Cloud.

I want to send emails and it doesn't not happen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.